# UICollectionView width suddenly doubles

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, uicollectionview

So for some reasons, the width of a collection view I am adding to another view doubles to 1536.... making half the items invisible/visible. The layout has 10 px to the left, 10px to the right. Then each cell has 20 px in between. They are 364px each. (Therefore 2 per row). I have around 10 items to display. In the following code all the logs print the correct width (768px):

```
if(!_productionLinesCollectionViewController)
{
    _productionLinesCollectionViewController = [[self storyboard]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductionLinesCollection"];
    _productionLinesCollectionViewController.productionLines = [_plant.productionLines allObjects];
}

NSLog(@" before adding it %f", _productionLinesCollectionViewController.collectionView.frame.size.width);
[[self scrollView] addSubview:_productionLinesCollectionViewController.view];
NSLog(@" after added it %f", _productionLinesCollectionViewController.collectionView.frame.size.width);
```

In the function **- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** I do the following:

```
     NSLog(@" cell for item at path %f", self.collectionView.frame.size.width);
```

and the width is now (for some reason) 1536. Any ideas? (I am using Storyboard).